# I have a bunch of LEGO pieces given to me already setup, any ideas to what set? Tan base with white and transparent cheese wedges?

Tags: piece-information, set-identification

These were already set up in a box of LEGO pieces that I got.  Anyone have an idea of what they might go to?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

They appear to be part of the [Sydney Opera House](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21012-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D) set:

[image]

It contains [that tan slope brick](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=93273&colorID=2&in=A):

[image: slope brick]

And those [white hinge brick bases](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3937&colorID=1&in=A):

[image: hinge brick]

And you can see those parts in that configuration.